# Angular TypeScript using enum with Spring Boot Backend

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have a question for a best practice. I want to use an enum for gender in a registration form in Angular. In my backend I use Spring Boot in Java and created the enum Gender.

What is now the way to show up the Gender values in the registration form? Should I implement the enum in TypeScript or how can I call it from Spring and is this efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the enum with string values, like this:

```
export enum Gender {
    MALE = 'MALE',
    FEMALE = 'FEMALE'
}
```

And in your component TS create a field to validate the enum in your template:

```
gender = Gender;
```

So, in your html template:

```
<div *ngIf="customer.gender === gender.MALE"></div>
```

**Remember, Typescript Enums are default Numeric.**

Comment: hi, i have the same situation, i've added enums in angular, but should i keep them in spring ?